# SQL Query for returning the latest date

Tags: mysql, sql

If I consider the following:

```
Customer | Date
 
100      |   09-06-2021 

100      |   17-03-2020
```

I am trying to find out the most recent date from the above, by using: select MAX(Date) from table, and it is returning `17-03-2020`, which is wrong.
How do I get the most recent date as `09-06-2021`?

Comment: Is your date stored as a varchar or date datatype?

Comment: It's being stored as varchar

Comment: cast it to a date, select top n value and order it accordingly

Comment: For a start, stop storing dates as varchar and use the right types. To solve your immediate problem, you need to convert the date from string to text before applying MAX

Comment: If you want the max string, then store strings. If you want the max date, then store dates. Storing strings and then expecting the max date is fubar. Especially when storing them in a non ISO format. Everything about your data storage choices is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong is that you are storing the date as a string, not a date.

You can fix your immediate problem by doing:

```
select max(str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y'))
from t;
```

But you should really fix the data.  Start by putting the date in a canonical format:

```
update t
    set date = str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Then modify the column to the correct data type:

```
alter table t modify column date date;
```